# Save a file by appending the original file name

Tags: java, file, append, savestate

I am running CFD simulation using Star-CCM+ which uses Java API. Star-CCM+ writes macros in java but I do not know the language at all. I want to manipulate parameter values in my simulations and then save the file with an appended name. For example, if my simulation is named "External Aero" I would like the simulation to save the file with the name "External Aero Heave". The reason for this is that multiple people will be using this macro and I don't want everyone's files being overwritten. So I want the macro to append the base file's name.

The code that Star-CCM+ wrote to save rename the file is as follows:

```
// Simcenter STAR-CCM+ macro: SaveOp.java
// Written by Simcenter STAR-CCM+ 15.06.008
package macro;

import java.util.*;

import star.common.*;
import star.base.neo.*;

public class SaveOp extends StarMacro {

  public void execute() {
    execute0();
  }

  private void execute0() {

    Simulation simulation_0 = getActiveSimulation();

    simulation_0.saveState("Y:\\CFD Simulation\\Run\\GFR21_Thesis_Base_ExportToPPT_Heave.sim");
  }

  private void execute1() {
  }
}
```

I can see that simulation_0 is the name of the active simulation. I have tried to add simulation_0 to the saveState command as follows:

```
    simulation_0.saveState("Y:\\CFD Simulation\\Run\\simulation_0_Heave.sim");
```

But this just saves a simulation named "simulation_0_Heave.sim", which is not what I am after.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note: the Star-CCM+ Java API documentation can be accessed from the Menu bar > Help > Java API, it will open in a browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
  simulation_0.saveState("Y:\\CFD Simulation\\Run\\" + simulation_0.getPresentationName() + "_Heave.sim");
```

Answer (score 0):

simulation_0 is not the name of the actual simulation
it is just an object of type Simulation.

You will need to , maybe, simulation_0.getName or simulation_0.getSimulationName() to get the name of the "simulation_0".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my issue and added code to add created files to a new directory.

```
      // making the file name extension string
  String append1 = "_Heave.sim";

  String dir1 = simulation_0.getSessionDir(); //getting the name of the sims directory
  
  String filename1 = simulation_0.getPresentationName(); //get the name of the current sim file

  String sep1 = System.getProperty("file.separator"); //get the right separator for your operative system

  String folder1 = (sep1 + filename1 + "_Five_Attitude_Study"); //making the first folders name

  String pathToNewDirectory1 = (dir1 + folder1); //applying it to the full path

  File fileObject1 = new File(pathToNewDirectory1); //making the new file folder

  Boolean yes1 = fileObject1.mkdir(); //checking that its there
  
  simulation_0.saveState(pathToNewDirectory1 + sep1 + filename1 + append1); //save the current sim file as| name_of_the_file@mod.sim
```